# refresh ListCtrl after drag and drop files

Tags: drag-and-drop, wxpython, listctrl

I'm relatively new to wxpython - really appreciate it any help you can offer me.  Basically, I'm having trouble closing the loop between

1)  filling a list called ListOfFiles in my OnDropFiles method below and 
2) refreshing the FileList so that it displays the items in ListOfFiles.

I know that if you call

```
FileWindow(None, -1, 'List of Files and Actions')
```

right at the end of OnDropFiles, it inits a new frame and draws from ListOfFiles when populating the FileList listctrl... but I was hoping there would be a way to update in the same window.  I've tried noodling around with Layout() and calling various methods on my FileWindowObject... but there's been no success.

Thanks so much for your help.  I think the answer you give me might lead to a real breakthrough in my understanding of wxpython.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx
import sys
import traceback
import time

APP_EXIT = 1
ListOfFiles = []


class FileDrop(wx.FileDropTarget):  #This is the file drop target
    def __init__(self, window):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)  #File Drop targets are subsets of windows
        self.window = window

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):   #FileDropTarget now fills in the ListOfFiles

        for DragAndDropFile in filenames:
            ListOfFiles.append(DragAndDropFile)  #We simply append to the bottom of our list of files.  

class FileWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):  #This will initiate with an id and a title
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(300, 300))

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)  #These are layout items
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)  #These are layout items

        self.FileList = wx.ListCtrl(panel, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT)  #This builds the list control box

        DropTarget = FileDrop(self.FileList)  #Establish the listctrl as a drop target
        self.FileList.SetDropTarget(DropTarget)  #Make drop target.

        self.FileList.InsertColumn(0,'Filename',width=140)  #Here we build the columns

        for i in ListOfFiles:  #Fill up listctrl starting with list of working files
            InsertedItem = self.FileList.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, i)  #Here we insert an item at the bottom of the list

        hbox.Add(self.FileList, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)
        self.Show(True)

def main():
    ex = wx.App(redirect = True, filename = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S.txt"))
    FileWindowObject = FileWindow(None, -1, 'List of Files and Actions')
    ex.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()  #Execute function#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all you're doing is adding items to a list, not to the ListCtrl itself. You need to subclass wx.ListCtrl and add an update method of some sort. Then you would call that update method instead of appending to a list you don't use anywhere. Here's one way to do it:

```
import wx
import time

########################################################################
class MyListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.index = 0

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def dropUpdate(self, path):
        """"""
        self.InsertStringItem(self.index, path)
        self.index += 1

class FileDrop(wx.FileDropTarget):  #This is the file drop target
    def __init__(self, window):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)  #File Drop targets are subsets of windows
        self.window = window

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):   #FileDropTarget now fills in the ListOfFiles

        for DragAndDropFile in filenames:
            self.window.dropUpdate(DragAndDropFile) # update list control


class FileWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):  #This will initiate with an id and a title
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(300, 300))

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)  #These are layout items
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)  #These are layout items

        self.FileList = MyListCtrl(panel)  #This builds the list control box

        DropTarget = FileDrop(self.FileList)  #Establish the listctrl as a drop target
        self.FileList.SetDropTarget(DropTarget)  #Make drop target.

        self.FileList.InsertColumn(0,'Filename',width=140)  #Here we build the columns

        hbox.Add(self.FileList, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)
        self.Show(True)

def main():
    ex = wx.App(redirect = True, filename = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S.txt"))
    FileWindowObject = FileWindow(None, -1, 'List of Files and Actions')
    ex.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```